# ignoring directories in os.walk()?

Tags: python

I wish to ignore some directories in my os.walk().

I do:

```
folders_to_ignore = ['C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\'];
def find_files(directory, pattern):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    dir[:] = [d for d in dirs if not is_folder_to_ignore(d)];
    for basename in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
            filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
            print("filename=" + filename);
```

I get:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\workspaces\pythonWS\FileUtils\findfiles.py", line 29, in find_files
  dir[:] = [d for d in dirs if not is_folder_to_ignore(d)];
```

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @mgilson I thought dirs updated this way see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141437/filtering-os-walk-dirs-and-files

Comment: @mgilson See the documentation on `os.walk` for what it means to in-place modify the directory list.

Comment: @dublintech -- you're right.  I skimmed through the docs (too) quickly and didn't see that modifying `dirs` in place does in fact make a different.  That's pretty cool.  Thanks for teaching me something new today!

Answer (score 15):

You're using [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) which is a built-in, probably you mean `dirs`

change this

```
dir[:] = [d for d in dirs if not is_folder_to_ignore(d)]
```

to this

```
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not is_folder_to_ignore(d)]
```