# How do I exclude directories when using os.walk()? Other methods haven't worked

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

So far the following code has been nothing but stubborn:

```
for root,subdirs,files in os.walk(topDir):
    for fileName in files:
        if fileName.endswith(("0.tif","0.png")):
            images.update({fileName[:-5]:Image(fileName,origin)})
        elif fileName.endswith((".tif",".png")):
            try:
                images.update({fileName[:-4]:Image(fileName,picLocations[fileName[:-4]])})
            except:
                images.update({fileName[:-4]:Image(fileName,origin)})
        else:
            pass
```

I've tried making the first three lines read:

```
exclude = set(["faces","animations"])
for root,subdirs,files in os.walk(topDir):
    subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if d not in exclude]
```

This, however, does not seem to filter out the unwanted items... am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Put a `print subdirs` before and after the `subdirs[:] =` line and see what happens.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, use Windows and have your actual directories named in a different fashion such as `Faces` or `Animations`? Then you might want to do `subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if d.lower() not in exclude]`.

Comment: Yes, I printed them out before and after, and it appeared to be working. Yes, i am using Windows 8, but the directories are all lower case. I've gotten it sorted out for the most part now though.

Comment: I know this is old but check my answer to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51871627/1896134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trythis

```
exclude = set(["faces","animations"])
for root,subdirs,files in os.walk(topDir):
    subdirs[:] = [d for d in set(subdirs)-exclude]
```

Comment: Thanks... not sure why that worked while the other ways didn't to be honest. Now I just have to figure out why it's naming all of the images incorrectly even though they are named via their file.

Comment: It produces the *same* result as `subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if d not in exclude]` except the order.

Comment: but, will this also _exclude_ subdirectories & files under them?