# Skip directories in list with os.walk?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, os.walk

I have a working function that generates a list from directories of images

```
def jpg_descended(folder):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(unicode(folder)):
        for extension in ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png'):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
                    matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return sorted(matches, key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)
```

but how can I get it to skip over directories I've put in a list?

```
excludes = ["october", "december"]
```

I want it to NOT return anything in directories named "october" or "december" or any other directories I may add to the excludes list.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exclude directories when using os.walk()? Other methods haven't worked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883084/how-do-i-exclude-directories-when-using-os-walk-other-methods-havent-worked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit `dirnames` in place by deleting directories that meet your requirements.  when `topdown=True` (the default) for `os.walk`, that prevents those directories from being enumerated.

Make sure it is an *in place* edit, for example:

```
dirnames[:] = [dirname for dirname in dirnames if dirname not in excludes]
```